# for loop to pull the highest score from the list

Tags: python

Print the highest score

```
student_scores = input("Input a list of student scores ").split()
for n in range(0, len(student_scores)):
  student_scores[n] = int(student_scores[n])
print(student_scores)

max = 0
for n in student_scores:
   max = max < n 
   max = n
print(f"The highest score in the class is: {max}")
```

Issues
the result is not expected like 78 65 89 86 55 91 64 89 it shows the highest score = 89 while it should be 91.

Advice
What is happening need some explanation why it is not working I know using if condition can solve the problem but want to know why this code is not working. If the score is not repeated it works but if the score repeats it takes that number as highest score.

I want to know why its not working if the highest score is repeated. It takes highest score of the number which is repeating the most

Answer (score 2):

You are unconditionally assigning each number to `max`. Thus `max` reflects the last number in the list despite it not being the *largest*.

You likely wanted:

```
max = 0
for n in student_scores:
  if max < n:
    max = n
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `max = max < n` is a comparison operation that results in a boolean value (either `True` or `False`). If the score `n` is larger than `max`, then `max` will be set to `True`, otherwise it will be `False`.

The next line, `max = n`, assigns the value of `n` to `max`, irrespective of whether `n` is actually the maximum so far or not. That's why you see the final value always returned.

You probably wanted to write something like this:

```
max_score = 0
for n in student_scores:
  max_score = max(max_score, n)
```

Note that it is also advisable to use more descriptive variable names and avoid builtin function names like `max`.

Comment: Or import `reduce` from `functools` and use something like: `reduce(max, map(int, "78 65 89 86 55 91 64 89".split()))`

Comment: Yes, that's nicer but I would steer away from functional paradigm at the moment for a beginner.

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved with good understanding.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The second method will be the most relevant to you, as you indicated you need to use a for loop. Always good to review built-in functions, however. :)

I'll cover two ways to approach this problem:

1. Use the built-in Python `max` function
2. Your way (basically recreating the `max` function)

The `max` function:

Code:

```
student_scores = input("Input a list of student scores ").split()
for n in range(0, len(student_scores)):
  student_scores[n] = int(student_scores[n])
print(student_scores)

print(f"The highest score in the class is: {max(student_scores)}")
```

The `max` function is used here with the list `student_scores`. Pass `student_scores` to it to retrieve the maximum value in the list.

Your way (with some adjustments):

```
student_scores = input("Input a list of student scores ").split()
for n in range(0, len(student_scores)):
  student_scores[n] = int(student_scores[n])
print(student_scores)


max_score = 0
for n in student_scores:
   if n > max_score:
      max_score = n
print(f"The highest score in the class is: {max_score}")
```

In your code, you need a conditional to compare the previously stored maximum value to the current value you are inspecting in the list. If the current value is greater than the previous maximum value, the maximum value should be updated accordingly. If it is not, we do nothing, and keep iterating through the list.

Note: Avoid using reserved Python keywords/function names as variable names (e.g., `max`). It won't always cause an issue, but it can, so it is best to avoid those names.

Both implementations print the below:

```
Input a list of student scores 
78 65 89 86 55 91 64 89
[78, 65, 89, 86, 55, 91, 64, 89]
The highest score in the class is: 91
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try not use the built-in function for variable name